# Can not set text to SKLabelNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I can't set the text to an SKLabelNode. Any ideas why this is happening?

I have tried doing like so:

```
let label = childNode(named:"ScoreLabel")
label.text = "Score: \(score)"
```

The text doesn't change. It stays as it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have provided too little information. Try deleting SKLabelNode and *creating it again* with the same parameters. Comment if it worked

Comment: No problem dude :)